# endian.h not found on mac osx

Tags: c, macos, header-files

I meet some trouble when I compile some C code on my mac which give me this error :

**fatal error: 'endian.h'
      file not found**

I did some google search about this problem.It seems like mac os x does not have header files like "endian.h", we have to create this file manually.

Then, I found this http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CarbonHeaders/CarbonHeaders-18.1/Endian.h which might be the file I am looking for but not sure.

But more troubles are coming.. where should I put this file?

**The file /usr/include does not exist.**

These are the folders in my /usr directory:

**X11       bin     libexec     share
X11R6       lib     sbin        standalone**

Could anyone help me to check the correctness of the endian.h file I found and tell me where to put this file in my mac please?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Xcode on OS X does not install the command-line tools by default. Depending on your
Xcode and OS X version you have to

- install the command line tools from the Xcode Preferences->Downloads window, or
- execute `xcode-select --install` from the Terminal command-line.

This will also install the "/usr/include" files, including "/usr/include/machine/endian.h".

For **Xcode 10** and later, see [Camille G.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52904079/1187415).

Comment: Yes, it works. I found the endian.h file in include/machine, but still can't compile the code correctly, the same error. Should I copy and paste endian.h to the /usr/include?

Comment: @geasssos: No, that would only be the last resort if nothing else works. - Does your project have a "configure" script? Perhaps that does not handle the OS X platform correctly. - Note also that "sys/types.h" already includes "machine/endian.h", so perhaps you don't have to include it explicitly.

Comment: Should i use **#include <machine/endian.h>** instead of **#include <endian.h>**?

Comment: @geasssos: I would include sys/types.h instead, but why don't you just try it?

Comment: Nope, sys/tyeps.h not working,but when i try to include<machine/endian.h> other error comes up but nothing about endian.h, seems this part of error has been solved.

Comment: FWIW: I needed to add ``-D_DARWIN_SOURCE`` at the gcc compile stage to include endian.h.

Comment: Adding the definitions [here](http://debugjournal.tumblr.com/post/99661010362/missing-byteswap-h-and-endian-h-on-mac-os-x) and adding -D_DARWIN_SOURCE to CFLAGS solved it for me.

Comment: This did not help for me on OSX 10.14.1 -- "command line tools are already installed".

Answer (score 16):

I just used `<machine/endian.h>` rather than `<endian.h>`.

It works.

As said in the first comment, `endian.h` is in `/usr/include/machine/` folder.

Comment: This helps but it still doesn't contain `htole32` which the Linux man pages call out here: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/endian.3.html

I know it is Linux versus Mac OS X. Just adding for people who might land on this from Google looking on how to get `htole32` quickly on Mac.

Comment: Does not apply to macOS 14 on ARM, there's no folder `/usr/include/machine/`

Answer (score 10):

Download and install the **Command Line Tools (macOS 10.X) for XCode 10.X** from Apple : https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

**Since MacOS 10.14 this will not create anymore the */usr/include* folder.**
This require the installation of an extra package that you could find on your computer after having installed the command-line tools :

*/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg*

Comment: This did not help for me on OSX 10.14.1; I still had the "failed to find endian.h" error. I ended up installing a later version of the software I was trying to build (numpy) and this error did not appear.

Comment: This created the /usr/include folder and worked perfectly for me

Comment: Please note that on OS X 10.14, installing `macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg` can fail. In that case you have to enter recovery mode (restart holding `Cmd+R` when the apple logo shows up), enter Terminal, type `csrutil disable`, restart, install the package, and then `csrutil enable` in recovery mode again.
The same applies if you cannot make changes inside `/usr/include` even with sudo.

Comment: These instructions appear to be out of date.  I have just installed the command line tools and there is no `Packages/` subdirectory under `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/`. `/usr/include` is not populated, but now there is a `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/` but that directory does *not* contain `endian.h` or `Endian.h`: at least `find` cannot find it.  So I'm afraid this answer badly needs updating.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue today. To solve the problem I did make a file named `endian.h` at `/usr/local/include/endian.h` that contains

```
#ifndef __FINK_ENDIANDEV_PKG_ENDIAN_H__
#define __FINK_ENDIANDEV_PKG_ENDIAN_H__ 1

/** compatibility header for endian.h
 * This is a simple compatibility shim to convert
 * BSD/Linux endian macros to the Mac OS X equivalents.
 * It is public domain.
 * */

#ifndef __APPLE__
    #warning "This header file (endian.h) is MacOS X specific.\n"
#endif  /* __APPLE__ */


#include <libkern/OSByteOrder.h>

#define htobe16(x) OSSwapHostToBigInt16(x)
#define htole16(x) OSSwapHostToLittleInt16(x)
#define be16toh(x) OSSwapBigToHostInt16(x)
#define le16toh(x) OSSwapLittleToHostInt16(x)

#define htobe32(x) OSSwapHostToBigInt32(x)
#define htole32(x) OSSwapHostToLittleInt32(x)
#define be32toh(x) OSSwapBigToHostInt32(x)
#define le32toh(x) OSSwapLittleToHostInt32(x)

#define htobe64(x) OSSwapHostToBigInt64(x)
#define htole64(x) OSSwapHostToLittleInt64(x)
#define be64toh(x) OSSwapBigToHostInt64(x)
#define le64toh(x) OSSwapLittleToHostInt64(x)


#endif  /* __FINK_ENDIANDEV_PKG_ENDIAN_H__ */
```

gist is

> https://gist.github.com/dendisuhubdy/19482135d26da86cdcf442b3724e0728

or just change the the header pointing to `endian.h` instead to

```
#if defined(OS_MACOSX)
  #include <machine/endian.h>
#elif defined(OS_SOLARIS)
  #include <sys/isa_defs.h>
  #ifdef _LITTLE_ENDIAN
    #define LITTLE_ENDIAN
  #else
    #define BIG_ENDIAN
  #endif
#elif defined(OS_FREEBSD) || defined(OS_OPENBSD) || defined(OS_NETBSD) ||\
      defined(OS_DRAGONFLYBSD)
  #include <sys/types.h>
  #include <sys/endian.h>
#else
  #include <endian.h>
#endif
```

Comment: The first option, the shim, still works in 2023 on M1 mac - the second one with `<machine/endian.h>` doesn't

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you should import "Endian.h"
check your disk manager, maybe your disk is case sensitive

Comment: I made the mistake of reformatting my disk with case-sensitive thinking it'd be a great idea years ago and it's still creeping in and breaking stuff all the time like this. This is why you properly capitalize your file paths regardless