# I encounter this error when I try 'pip install StyleFrame', any idea what this error is about?

Tags: python, styleframe

I encounter this error when I try 'pip install StyleFrame', any idea what this error is about?

```
Command "/Users/pengdanni/Desktop/invoice/venv/bin/python 
-m pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/g9/1p5yfql51vs118b1r6899rp80000gn/T/pip-build-env-y8qav8ta
--no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: 
--only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- wheel setuptools Cython "

 numpy==1.9.3; python_version=='3.5'" "numpy==1.12.1; 
 python_version=='3.6'" "numpy==1.13.1; python_version>='3.7'"" 

 failed with error code 1 in None
```

Comment: What version of Python do you have installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:

1. You *might* need to install xcrun: `xcode-select --install`
2. If you're using python 3.7, styleframe is not compatible at the moment.  I made a [github issue](https://github.com/DeepSpace2/StyleFrame/issues/52) for them.  Until that's addressed, if you can downgrade to python 3.6 it should work.

---

Longer answer with my troubleshooting steps:

Some python packages require xcrun to install on some operating systems (like OSX on a mac).  This is part of the (rather verbose) error output I got when replicating your issue:

> xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

I ran this to install xcrun:

```
xcode-select --install
```

which gave me a new even longer error that included:

> _configtest.c:1:10: fatal error: 'endian.h' file not found

That led me to this:
[endian.h not found on mac osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813028/endian-h-not-found-on-mac-osx/52904079#52904079)

But it still failed with the same error.

Further details in the github issue: https://github.com/DeepSpace2/StyleFrame/issues/52

Comment: The issue is was closed / resolved, but I still get the error