# Cannot include <endian.h> when generating SWIG bindings

Tags: swig

Here's my preprocessor section in my C++ code which I want to generate SWIG bindings.

```c
#if defined(__FreeBSD__) || defined(__APPLE__) || defined(__FreeBSD_kernel__) \
|| defined(__OpenBSD__)
#include <machine/endian.h>
#endif
    
#if defined(__linux__) || defined(__CYGWIN__) || defined(__GNU__) || \
defined(ANDROID)
#include <endian.h>
#endif
    
#ifdef __MINGW32__
#include <sys/param.h>
#endif
    
#ifdef _MSC_VER
/* _MSVC lacks BYTE_ORDER and LITTLE_ENDIAN */
#define LITTLE_ENDIAN 0x0001
#define BYTE_ORDER LITTLE_ENDIAN
#endif
    
#if !defined(BYTE_ORDER) || !defined(LITTLE_ENDIAN)
#error No byte order defined
#endif
    
#if BYTE_ORDER == LITTLE_ENDIAN
# define HIOFFSET 1
# define LOWOFFSET 0
#else
# define HIOFFSET 0    /* word offset to find MSB */
# define LOWOFFSET 1    /* word offset to find LSB */
#endif
```

But when I try to generate SWIG bindings using the `swig` command, I get the following error:

> Error: CPP #error "No byte order defined". Use the -cpperraswarn
> option to continue swig processing.

It seems when SWIG tries to generate the bindings, `<machine/endian.h>` is not being included for some reasons.

How can I fix this error? Do I need to add anything to the SWIG interface file?

I'm using macOS 10.14.4.

---

**ADDED**: Here's what my SWIG interface file looks like.

```
%module pd
%{
    #include "myBindings.h"
%}
%include "myBindings.h"
```

As you can see there's nothing special in it.

And I generate the bindings using the following command:

```
swig -c++ -lua -fcompact -fvirtual -I../../../libs/openFrameworks myBindings.i && mv myBindings_wrap.cxx myBindings.cpp
```

Then I get the above mentioned error.
Even when I just leave `#include <machine/endian.h>` it still generates the same error. (`No byte order defined`)

Comment: I will offer bounty for anyone who answers this.

Comment: Show your SWIG interface file.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I don't have anything special in it.

Comment: Well, the basic one I threw together compiled with no errors, so I'll show you mine if you show me yours :^) Anyway I'm on Windows so check the predefined macros for your compiler match one of the #if defined you're expecting. Also, it was the compiler not the swig command that failed for me when I forced the _MSC_VER to be undefined to simulate the issue so that indicates your .i might be incorrect.  Provide all the information to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Please see my edited post.

Comment: I reproduced it with your .i.  I was using `%inline %{ #include "test.h" %}` which *should* be equivalent, but it only fails with separate #include and %include of the header.  So it **is** special :^)  Not sure yet why one works and one fails, but did you try using the suggested `-cpperraswarn` and continue building?  the wrap file still gets generated.  You may need `-D<symbol>` and define the symbols your compiler will use to generate the code correctly.

Comment: Tell swig where it is stored, add `-I/usr/include`.  If you don't have /usr/include/machine/endian.h then [install it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20813118/17034).

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks but I'm using macOS 10.14 and it does not create the /usr/include folder anymore.

Comment: That's surely why you need to install it.

Comment: @Hans I reproduced the error on Windows so it isn't a case of needing the file installed (at least for the current error).  It happens during the SWIG step before the compiler will care if the file is installed.

Comment: @Zack did you try using `-cpperraswarn` and continuing the build?  It's the compiler that will care about the preprocessor error.  SWIG should be able to ignore it.  As Hans said, the *compiler* will care if the file needs to be present, and may need to be installed or the path included.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Yeah it works when I do that. Thanks. So is it safe to just ignore the error by SWIG?

Comment: Yes, it is just a code generator. Move on and compile and test the result.  Swig doesn’t normally process #include files inside files you have %included, so it won’t receive the definition inside endian.h, but the compiler will process normally.  You could also %include the endian.h file if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason SWIG is failing is because it doesn't normally recurse into include files when you `%include` a file to wrap its interface, so the definitions defined in `<machine/endian.h>` are not processed.

There are a number of options to remedy this:

1. Use `-cpperraswarn` and ignore the error as suggested. SWIG will process the #if incorrectly, but it is the *compiler* that builds the value.  SWIG will still expose the `HIOFFSET` and `LOWOFFSET` values in the wrapper, and the value will be correct.
2. `%include <machine/endian.h>` explicitly.  That may or may not work correctly depending on the content of the file, and may expose more variables in the SWIG wrapper than intended.
3. Use `-includeall` with SWIG to explicitly recurse into all #include files.  This is normally not wanted as SWIG will attempt to wrap all definitions.  For example, you'd get everything in `#include <stdio.h>` if present.
4. Explicitly define `BYTE_ORDER` and/or `LITTLE_ENDIAN` in the SWIG .i file to work around the issue.

Here's a couple of examples:

### --cpperraswarn Solution:

#### test.i

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%include "test.h"
```

SWIG generates the warning, and the result is only `HIOFFSET` and `LOWOFFSET` are defined, but they are correct for my little-endian machine even with the error from SWIG.  The compiler still processed the definition correctly.

```
>>> import test
>>> dir(test)
['HIOFFSET', 'LOWOFFSET', 'SWIG_PyInstanceMethod_New', '__builtin__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '_swig_getattr', '_swig_property', '_swig_repr', '_swig_setattr', '_swig_setattr_nondynamic', '_swig_setattr_nondynamic_method', '_test']
>>> test.HIOFFSET
1
```

### %include endian.h Solution:

In this case I have a Windows machine so I simulated the problem by creating an `msvc_endian.h` file and defining `BYTE_ORDER` and `LITTLE_ENDIAN` in it.

**test.h** was modified to use the following snippet:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#include "msvc_endian.h"
#endif
```

**test.i** explicitly processed the header:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%include "msvc_endian.h"
%include "test.h"
```

**msvc_endian.h**

```
#define LITTLE_ENDIAN 0x0001
#define BYTE_ORDER LITTLE_ENDIAN
```

SWIG now has no warning and the result is still correct, but due to processing the sub-header `LITTLE_ENDIAN` and `BYTE_ORDER` were also exposed as values in the wrapper:

```
>>> import test
>>> dir(test)
['BYTE_ORDER', 'HIOFFSET', 'LITTLE_ENDIAN', 'LOWOFFSET', 'SWIG_PyInstanceMethod_New', '__builtin__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '_swig_getattr', '_swig_property', '_swig_repr', '_swig_setattr', '_swig_setattr_nondynamic', '_swig_setattr_nondynamic_method', '_test']
>>> test.HIOFFSET
1
```